# "Confirm Form Resubmission" popup/error (after login error) in Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-form

I am getting "Confirm Form Resubmission" pop up-

1) When refresh the page (after login errors).

2) When press browser's back button after submit of the login page (after login errors).

My controller code is:

```
// Showing Login Page
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("credentials", new Credentials());
    return "login";
}

// Submitting Login Form
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("credentials") Credentials credentials,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        // Validation on Login form fields
        validator.validate(credentials, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        }

        return "redirect:success";
}
```

My steps are:

**Case 1:**

i) Left username blank and click on login button. This will show error "username can not be left blank"

ii) Now refresh the page. Then I will get the "Confirm Form Resubmission" pop up.

**Case 2:**

i) Repeat step 1 of case 1

ii) Then fill all the field correctly and then click on Login button. User will be redirect to success.jsp page

iii) now click on back button of browser and I will get "Confirm Form Resubmission" error on the page.

How can I remove this problem. Where is the mistake in my code ? Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: there is no mistake in your code. this is standard browser behavior on pages where you are making HTTP POST requests. If you want to override  this behavior you will have to write your own code.

Comment: Confirm Form Resubmission has any JavaScript written?

Comment: Why spring-webflow tag? There doesn't seem to be anything related to it in the question, but maybe you're using it and think it could be related to the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than forwarding to the `login` jsp on error, you could save the `BindingResult` in `RedirectAttributes` and then redirect to `login` instead. The resulting POST-REDIRECT-GET should then resolve the "confirm form resubmission" issue for login errors.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("credentials") Credentials credentials,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes attrs) {

        // Validation on Login form fields
        validator.validate(credentials, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            attrs.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.credentials", result);
            attrs.addFlashAttribute("credentials", credentials);
            return "redirect:login"; // Redirect to login, rather than forward
        }

        return "redirect:success";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Will Keeling. But this is not working. Now it is not showing any error message on login page. Am I needing to make any changes in Get method too? And I am also not able to go on success page if there is no error. It always keeps me on login page. Please suggest me. I used your code as such.

Comment: @ManojAgarwal - are you using Spring 3.1 or above?

Comment: Yes, I am using Spring 3.1